# different rect of view in iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, landscape-portrait

I have this code (use Landscape orientation like)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

and code in viewDidLoad

```
CGSize viewSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])){
    viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.height, viewSize.width);

} else {
    viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height);
}

rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height);
```

in iOS 5 rect (x=0,y=0,width=320,height=480)

in iOS 6 rect (x=0,y=0,width=480,height=320)

how to fix to iOS 5 different rect

**UPDATE**

in viewDidAppear all OK

Comment: Well, test which version you have installed, I guess.  Certainly not the first difference between 5 and 6, but efforts to create a list of differences here get quashed.

Comment: (People don't test the screen size very often -- usually they check a view on the screen, and the views behave a hair more predictably.)

Comment: ok, if I use code like rect = self.view.bounds I got the same result like I need, but this is no for iPhone 5